Closed character formula for the module $L(a\omega_i)$
Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a complex finite-dimensional simple Lie algebra with a fixed Cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}$. Assume that $\omega_1, \omega_2, \dots, \omega_n\in\mathfrak{h}^{*}$ is the fundamental dominant weights with respect to a basis of $\mathfrak{h}$: $h_1,h_2,\dots,h_n$.  For any $\lambda \in \mathfrak{h}^{*}$, denote by $L(\lambda)$ the irreducible highest weight module. As we know, there exists an algorithm to compute the character of the module $L(\lambda)$ by using the Kazhdan–Lusztig polynomial. However, this method is too complex in general.
Recently, I read a paper written by B. J. Wilson: Highest-weight theory for truncated current Lie algebras, J. Algebra, 2011. In that paper, the author gave an irreduciblility criteria about the Verma module over the truncated Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}\otimes \mathbb{C}[t]/(t^{N+1})$.
This paper helps me to solve my problem to the case of $N>0$. But for the case of $N=0$, the truncated Lie algebra is just isomorphic to the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. I need to obtain a closed formula about the character of the following irreducible highest weight module $$L(a \omega_i),$$ where $a\in \mathbb{C}$. Does there exist such a closed formula like the finite-dimensional irreducible module? Remark. If $a\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0},$ then we have done it. If $a \notin \mathbb{Z},$ we also get it by using  Theorem $11$ in  W. Soergel, Kategorie O, perverse Garben und Moduln uber den Koinvarianten zur
Weylgruppe, J. Am. Math. Soc. 3(2) (1990), 421–445. Thus, the remaining case of $a \in \mathbb{Z}_{<0}$ is not known for me.
